# ValueError: I/O operation in closed file

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I'm getting an `ValueError: I/O operation in closed file` when running a python code. I believe this is the part that's causing the problem:

```
fn = './seenFrontPagePosts.txt'

try:
    f = open(fn, 'r+')
except IOError:
    f = open(fn, 'w+')

try:
    frontOld = json.loads(f.readline())
except:
    frontOld = []

for post in redditFrontPage:
    if str(post.subreddit) == subreddit:
        print("We have a post on r/all! '{}'".format(post.title))
        if str(post.id) not in frontOld:
            print("We haven't seen it before!")
            message = post.reply(allMessage)
            message.distinguish(sticky=True)

            frontOld.append(str(post.id))
        else:
            print("We have seen it before.")
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(json.dumps(frontOld))
    f.close()
```

How do I fix the error? Is the syntax off or is it something more complicated?

Here's the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pythonCode.py", line 60, in <module>
    f.seek(0)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Answer (score 2):

After one iteration of the outermost loop, `f.close()` closes the file. So, the next time you reach `f.seek(0)` it encounters the closed file and throws the error. You need to do `open` in the beginning of the outermost loop

Answer (score 1):

You are looping through elements in a list `redditFrontPage` and within that loop you are closing the file `f`. So then on the next iteration, you are trying to perform some operation on the file but it is closed.

You need to either open the file within the loop, or not close the file within the loop.